# multiple testcase classes in the same module, how to run them as whole or single test with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module that I use to hold specific testcase classes. I would like to implement an easy way to run them all or one by one.

I did notice that if I run pytest passing the whole module, all the test will run; but I would like also to pass one single testcase, if I want to.

Is this possible or do I need one module per testcase class?

Comment: You can use [test-markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html) to run particular test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chanda for giving me a solution.

test markers are very useful! Also another way to run a specific test class is to have the `-k` option, which will run only a specific testcase class in a module, skipping the others